# Parrot OS is stuck on a login loop

Tags: linux, parrot-os

I start my computer and go on parrot os, everything is normal but when I try to login, it sends me into a black screen and shows me the parrot os login again. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Get a terminal session before login and run:   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove    .... Restart and test.

Comment: @John That didn't work, it's still stuck in the login loop.

Comment: You may need to reinstall Parrot

Answer (score 1):

What i did was :
Insert the usb installation media
Reboot
I have a hp laptop so i pressed F9
From the parrot install menu choose
Advanced mode
Then terminal mode and enter
Wait for the terminal to sho

And finally

sudo apt full-upgrade -y

And reboot at the end

Helped me

Answer (score 0):

Just log in and type this command rm -rf ~/.cache and hit enter it will automatically reboot to gui login

Comment: Ho is the OP going to do this